# Push iOs notifications spanish characters

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with the Spanish character 'ñ' and push iOs notifications.
I send notifications using a PHP script. Before send it I encode the message as utf8 and it is well done. The problem is that when I send the notification with a 'ñ' in the payload I don't receive it, but with other special character as 'á', 'é',..., I receive it without any problem.

```
$text = "España";
$json = '{"data":{"text":"' . $text . '"}}';
$passphrase = 'passphase';  
$message = utf8_encode($json);
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
      'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
      $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken[$i]) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
   echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
   echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
```

EDIT:

Special characters as 'ñ' are sent correctly, my problem was that I sent more data than $text ($text variable was written to explain the code better). In iOs push notifications there is a payload size limit and my message exceeded it, so the device didn't received it. It only happened with one text in my application, because it was the largest, and it was the only one with an 'ñ'.
So, if you don't receive some message check the number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using entites.

```
$text="Espa&ntilde;a"
...
```

Saludos desde Suiza